# Visualizing data in an expressjs and JADE environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I am trying to visualize some Data with d3 which is stored inside of a MongoDB. My question is about something like a best practice to create `div` elements for every data through the JADE template and afterwards call a method to draw different charts.
My main problem is that I am losing the reference to my data after displaying the HTML file and I do not want to query the DB a second time.

**Schema**

```
# Create Schema
executionSchema = new Schema(
  timestamp: Number,
  components: [{
    uid: String,
    type: { type: String },
    samples: [Number],
    execution_times: [Number]
  }]
)
```

The data is initially retrieved and given to the JADE template:

**Index coffee**

```
exports.index = (req, res) ->
    Execution.find (err, executions, count) ->
        res.render "index", title: "Debugger", executions: executions
        return
    return
```

Afterwads, the index.JADE creates `divs` for every `component` inside of execution[0]

```
- each component in executions[0].components
    div(class="panel panel-primary")
      div(class="panel-heading") UID: #{component.uid}
      div(class="panel-body")
        p(style='white-space:pre;')
          | Type: #{component.type}
        - var uid = component.uid
        div(id=uid)
```

This is everything right now, since I am not able to call a JavaScript method outside of the JADE file. Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this data to be available on the clientside script without actually querying the db the second time?

You have two options here. The first one is to just add this line right bellow your current Jade code:

```
- each component in executions[0].components
    // div creation stuff here
    // ...

script
    window.executions = JSON.stringify(executions);
```

Now your client-side scripts will be able to access the executions object and access that data like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(executions);
```

Not sure if this is efficient though. If you do not want to query the db for the second time, it could be because the dataset is large or db slow?

Well the other way to do this with only a single db query is to render the page without the divs, and do not query the db at all. Then use the Javascript to fetch the executions (ajax call) and render it client-side once the data is loaded.

That depends on your use case though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now I am building just the divs and add data by ajax calls.

Comment: That is how I would do it. Render stuff like views in one go. Get data in another process. Unless you're looking for super-super-fast, then just render everything on the server and use no javascript at all :)